# couldn't find the open translations editor in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm watching a tutorial about change the text for different languages but I can't find same options as the tutorial go through so where can I able to find it ?
please check out image for more detail ,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku2eK.jpg)

I couldn't find that option

Answer (score 0):

First, you must create a folder named values-languages_code and create a `strings.xml` file inside. This new file will contains the translation in the new language (different from English).

For example, if you want to translate in french, you will have a repository like:

- values

  - strings.xml
- values-fr

  - strings.xml

After doing it right-click again on `strings.xml` file and you will have the option for translation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside "strings.xml", click "Open editor" on the top right prompt. Or right click "strings.xml" on the left panel -> "Open Translations Editor".
2. Click on the "earch" icon, which shows "Add Locale" -> select target country.
3. Enter translated text.